# Why do we define modules to be over *abelian* groups?

Tags: soft-question, modules

We define a module to be an *abelian* group $M$ together with a ring action $R \times M \to M$ that satisfies certain properties. **Q:** Why do we require that $M$ is abelian?

I know that modules generalize vector spaces and abelian groups and, in a sense, representations. But why not take it further and relax the underlying group? I'm curious about whether this definition simply produces a more manageable collection of objects, et cetera. On a related note, what can be said when $M$ is not abelian?

Comment: This [1](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/609364/why-is-ring-addition-commutative), [2](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/346375/commutative-property-of-ring-addition) are analogous question for rings, and the "same" proof that is redundant that in module case.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let $R$ be a ring with $1$.  If $M$ is a group, written multiplicatively, equipped with an $R$-action, then, for any $x,y\in M$, $(xy)^2 = (1+1)\cdot (xy) = [(1+1)\cdot x][(1+1)\cdot y] = x^2 y^2$.  So $yx=xy$, and $M$ is abelian.

If $R$ doesn't have a $1$, then we conclude only that $rM$ is abelian for all $r\in R$.  In this case, we might be able to define noncommutative modules, but they are likely to be very awkward.  For example, let $R=\{0,\epsilon\}$ with $\epsilon+\epsilon=\epsilon^2=0$, which is the simplest non-unital ring.  Then a noncommutative $R$-module can be described by a group $G$, a normal subgroup $N\lhd G$, and an abelian subgroup $A \leq N$ isomorphic to $G/N$ (the quotient $G\to G/N$ is the multiplication map $\epsilon\cdot: G\to \epsilon G$).  Understanding the ways this can happen is very subtle, probably intractable, and certainly only tangentially related to the study of $R$.

Another perspective: a module is just a quotient of a free module.  So if we want noncommutative modules, then we want to consider, for example, $R * R$, the amalgamated product, to be a module over $R$.  But $r(R*R)=(rR)*(rR)$ is never abelian unless $rR=0$, so this is only an $R$-module when $R$ has trivial multiplication.

In short, addition should always be commutative.  If I really wanted to think of a non-abelian group as a module over something, I would probably work over a semigroup $S$, and define an $S$-module to be a group $G$ and a semigroup homomorphism $S\to\operatorname{End}(G)$ (one way to define an $R$-module is an abelian group $M$ with a homomorphism of rings $R\to \operatorname{End}(M)$).

Answer (score 11):

Aside from the observation that has already been made in other comments that the other module axioms already force a module to be abelian, let me make the following philosophical remarks.

Rings naturally want to act on abelian groups, in the following sense: you can make sense of the notion of [monoid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid) $M$ in any [monoidal category](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoidal_category) $(V, \otimes)$, and once you have a monoid one very natural notion of an action of that monoid is another object $S$ in $V$ and an action map $M \otimes S \to S$ satisfying certain axioms. For example:

- If $V = (\text{Set}, \times)$, then a monoid in $V$ is a monoid (e.g. a group) in the usual sense and a monoid action is a set on which the monoid acts in the usual sense.
- If $V = (\text{Top}, \times)$, then a monoid in $V$ is a topological monoid (e.g. a topological group, e.g. a Lie group) and a monoid action is a topological space on which the monoid acts continuously.
- If $V = (\text{Ab}, \otimes)$, then a monoid in $V$ is a ring (exercise!) and a monoid action is a module over the ring in the usual sense.

So there's a fairly general definition of what it means for a monoid to act on something, and applied to rings-as-monoids-in-$\text{Ab}$ it reproduces the usual notion of module.

Actually there is another very general thing we can do. We can make sense of what it means for a monoid in $V$ to act on an object of any category which is [enriched](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enriched_category) over $V$: namely, if $M$ is a monoid in $V$ and $C$ is a $V$-enriched category, then a monoid action on an object $S$ in $C$ is a morphism $M \to \text{End}(S)$ of monoids (in $V$). For example:

- If $V = (\text{Set}, \times)$, then a $V$-enriched category is a (locally small) category, so monoids can act on objects in essentially any category.
- If $V = (\text{Ab}, \otimes)$, then a $V$-enriched category is a [preadditive category](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preadditive_category) (e.g. an abelian category), so rings can act on objects in any such category. Examples include categories of chain complexes or sheaves of abelian groups.

The first construction becomes a special case of the second construction if $V$ is [closed monoidal](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/closed+monoidal+category); in this case specifying an action map $M \otimes S \to S$ is the same as specifying a map $M \to [S, S]$, where brackets denote [internal hom](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/internal+hom), and the axioms required of an action map are equivalent to requiring that this map $M \to [S, S]$ is a morphism of monoids.

The monoidal category of abelian groups under tensor product is closed monoidal, so the above remarks apply to it. In particular, if $A$ and $B$ are any two abelian groups, then the set $\text{Hom}(A, B)$ of homomorphisms between them naturally acquires an abelian group structure. This means that if $A$ is an abelian group, then $\text{End}(A)$ naturally has an abelian group structure in addition to a second monoid structure given by composition; in fact, it's naturally a ring, the universal ring acting on $A$. This doesn't happen for not-necessarily-abelian groups.

The category of abelian groups is really something special all on its own. It is not just a convenient subcategory of the category of groups; it really has its own structure that the category of groups fails to have. (Groups have their own structure, though: the category of groups can be enriched over the category of *groupoids*. But that's another story.)

Comment: For a reference for why an action map $M\otimes S\to S$ is the same as a monoid morphism $M\to [S,S]$, see http://mathoverflow.net/a/146565/6249 .

Answer (score 6):

> **Proposition.** Let $R$ denote a unital ring. Suppose $M$ is an $R$-module whose underlying group is not necessarily abelian. Then $M$'s underlying group is abelian.
>
> *Proof.* Consider $x,y \in M$. Then $2(x+y) = 2x+2y$, where $2$ is shorthand for $1_R+1_R$. So $x+y+x+y = x+x+y+y$. By cancellation,
>   $y+x=x+y$.

So if we're going to consider non-abelian modules, then we should also drop the condition that $a(x+y) = ax+ay$ for all $a \in R$ and all $x,y \in M$. Once we've done this, there are lots of examples of such things. For instance, any group, denoted additively, becomes a non-abelian $\mathbb{Z}$-module as follows.

$$nx = \underbrace{x +\cdots + x}_n, \qquad 0x = 0, \qquad (-1)x = -x$$

This satisfies all the module axioms we're used to, except for $n(x+y) = nx+ny$ which clearly does not hold. Observe, in particular, that the axiom $(a+b)x = ax+bx$ still holds.

Anyway, since we've dropped one of our "distributivity" laws, namely $a(x+y)=ax+ay$, it probably makes sense to allow $R$ to be an arbitrary [near-ring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Near-ring).