# Vector space over a set which is not commutative

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I was wondering whether you could have a vector space over a set of elements $S$ which do not satisfy all of the Abelian group properties. That is since scalar multiplication and vector addition are just functions, could you define them in such a way that it compensates the lack of commutativeness/associativeness in the set $S$?

Comment: You can define such a structure. That won’t be a vector space though.

Comment: As soon as you have a group which admits scalar multiplication, it _must_ be abelian (provided $1$ is a valid scalar). See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/924431/why-do-we-define-modules-to-be-over-abelian-groups) for instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A vector space, by definition, is defined over a *field*, which is a set that satisfies the Abelian group properties.

So no, you cannot define a vector space over a set of elements which is not Abelian, because whatever you define will, *by definition*, not be a vector space.

Answer (score 6):

As others say, it won't be a vector space since it does not satisfy the axioms.  However, you can have similar structures with more relaxed axioms.  One case that is commonly studied is a module over a ring.

[Module at Wolfram](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Module.html)