# What happens when you don't require rings to be abelian groups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, noncommutative-algebra

My question is as stated in the title: What do we lose when we drop the condition that a ring $R$ be an abelian group (i.e. it may be the case that $a+b \neq b+a$ for some $a,b \in R$).

If we allow this condition then we may consider, for example, any group $G$ to be a (noncommutative) ring with multiplication being conjugation in $G$ and addition being multiplication in $G$. In such a "ring" $G$, we always have $0=1$, so I suspect things might get strange.

Has anyone thought at all about such objects? Are they entirely uninteresting?

Comment: This answer may help you: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/346682/133781

Comment: @Xammm It definitely does, thank you!

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/609364/why-is-ring-addition-commutative?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: They (semirings) tend to be more interesting to computer scientists (who find them *very* interesting) than mathematicians.  Computer scientists in general tend to be more interesting in monoids than groups.

Comment: Well, since this question is about dropping *commutativity* of the underlying group (not inverses), semirings are not so relevant as [nearrings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Near-ring).